# Mass of a complex shape

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics, volume

I am having some issue calculating the mass of a shape. I am having trouble with the volume of the shape * density.

The material density is $7.85 \rm g/cc$ or $7.85 \rm g/cm^3$

1 rectangular prism: $L=600\rm mm$ $W=15\rm mm$ $H=600\rm mm$
$v = 5.4x10^6\rm mm^3$

subtract $6$ cylinders: $R=8 \rm mm$
$v = 6*(3.016x10^3\rm mm^3)$

subtract $4$ rectangular prism: $\rm L=280\ mm\  W=15\ mm\ H=20\ mm
\ v = 4*(8.4x10^4\ mm^3)$

subtract $4$ triangles $\rm B=280\ mm\  H=280 \ mm\  W=15\ mm\ 
v = 4*(5.88x10^5 \ mm^3)$

subtract $1$ hexagon $\rm S=70\ mm\  H=15\ mm\
v = 19.0959x10^4\ mm^3$

$\rm v = 5.4x10^6\ mm^3 - 6*(3.016x10^3\ mm^3) - 4*(8.4x10^4\ mm^3) - 4*(5.88x10^5\ mm^3) - 19.0959x10^4\ mm^3$

$\rm =5.4x10^6\ mm^3 - 0.018096x10^6\ mm^3 - 0.336x10^6\ mm^3 - 2.352x10^6\ mm^3 - 0.190959x10^6\ mm^3$

$\rm v = 2.502945x10^6\ mm^3 = 2,502,945\ mm^3$

The density of this material is $\rm 7.85 \ g/cm^3$

This is where I am running into serious issues.

When I multiply the volume x density I get numbers that doesn't seem right;

I am pretty sure that I am failing to do some conversion between $\rm cm^3$ to $\ mm^3$ or something along those lines but I am just not sure.

$\rm 1cm = 10mm$ I know that but I just can't seem to get the correct answer mathematically.

Can anyone explain how to get the correct answer from this position
$\rm v = 2.502945x10^6\ mm^3 = 2,502,945\ mm^3$
density = $\rm 7.85\ g/cm^3$

Comment: Please use `$ $` around math equations and numbers from next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $1 \text{cm} = 10 \text{mm}$ which implies that $1 \text{cm}^3 = 10^3 \text{mm}^3$. If you are having trouble seeing this, draw a cube of $1 \text{cm}^3$. Each of its sides is $10 \text{mm}$. From this it is clear what the volume is in $\text{mm}^3$.

So you have that

$$
\frac{7.85 \text{ grams}}{1 \text{ cm}^3}= \frac{7.85 \text{ grams}}{1 \text{ cm}^3} \cdot \frac{1 \text{ cm}^3}{10^3 \text{ mm}^3} = 0.00785 \frac{\text{g}}{\text{mm}^3}
$$

And the result you are looking for is

$$
\text{Mass} = \left (0.00785 \frac{\text{g}}{\text{mm}^3} \right) \left(2.502945 \cdot 10^6 \text{ mm}^3 \right)
$$

Comment: shouldn't it be 2.502945x10^6mm3; also multiplying it out I get 19648.11825; I am still confused as to working out the last part of the problem.
would you be able to show the steps just like you did with the g/cm3 -> g/mm3 conversion?

Comment: Oops, yes it should be $10^6$. And The answer you are getting is also what I get. Is there a reason why you think this is wrong? (Note, I didn't go through all of the calculations you showed to see if it was all right. I just started from the end where you asked).

Comment: 2502945*0.00785=19648.11825; 19,648 how do I go from that to a mass? This is the part that's confusing me, it's obvious that this piece of material cannot be that heavy. I'm not sure what to do next with that 19,648 number.

Comment: omg, this is such a simple oversight that I feel terribly foolish! 19,648 is in grams; 1000grams = 1kg. So the final answer is 19.6Kg.

Comment: Yep! $19.6 \text{kg}$ seems reasonable, hence why I asked before why you thought the answer was wrong. Glad you figured it out!